# Quantum Many Body Problem - Neural Networks

Tags: quantum-information

I've recently read [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.02318) and subsequently found its [corresponding Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network_quantum_states).

Could someone more educated than me explain the consequences of neural network quantum states?

It seems that they are "training" the neural net based on the variational principle, and somehow this is leading to a tractable calculation of the wavefunction.

Is it surprising that they are able to use this neural net "black box" to simulate quantum computations on a classical computer? Are there theoretical limits to this approach?

Comment: what does "consequences of neural network quantum states" mean? Also, what sorts of "theoretical limits" are you thinking about?